# Turn on anonymous access to sharepoint, navigation is now not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We turned on anonymous access to sharepoint and it seems our site navigation is now not being  shown.

We can access the pages directly when anonymous, but the full menu's don't appear until AFTEr we login.

I can't seem to find anything in the Navigation setup under Site > Site Settings > Modify Navigation to say 'show option if anonymous'.

Just throughly confused, non of the sharepoint doc's I've found about anonymous access seems to mention navigation changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its an interaction between 'Audience Targeting' and Anonymous access.

The 'Pages' list has audience targeting turned on, but none of the audience target values have been set for the pages.

Once I target a page to 'All Site USers' then it appears to unauthenticated users.

Sigh.